Is a signed measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ characterized by the transform $\mathcal{L}_\mu (\lambda ):=\int e^{\langle \lambda,x\rangle }\mu (dx)$?
In the book "Probability Theory" by Achim Klenke there's the following theorem: a finite measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty )$ is characterized by its Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda):=\int e^{-\lambda x}\mu(dx)$ for $\lambda\geq 0$.
Is there a similar theorem for finite signed measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$? What I mean is, is a signed measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ characterized by the transform $\mathcal{L}_\mu (\lambda ):=\int e^{\langle \lambda,x\rangle }\mu (dx)$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^d$?
I spent a lot of time trying to find a reference dealing with this case, but I didn't find any.
If possible, please provide me a reference about it (preferably a book).

Why should the integral defining the transform converge?

For signed measures, we cannot assume that $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)$ converges for all $\lambda$ unless we make assumptions about the measure $\lambda$, so assume that $\mu$ has compact support.
In the case that $\mu$ has compact support $C$, we can use standard analysis techniques to conclude that if $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)=0$ for all $\lambda$, then $\mu=0$. Suppose that $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)=0$ for all $\lambda$. Then $\int c_1e^{\langle \lambda_1,x\rangle}+\dots+c_re^{\langle \lambda_r,x\rangle}d\mu(x)=0$ whenever $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r$ are vectors and $c_1,\dots,c_r$ are scalars. But the collection of functions of the form $c_1e^{\langle \lambda_1,x\rangle}+\dots+c_re^{\langle \lambda_r,x\rangle}$ forms a separative algebra over the field of real numbers, so by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, every continuous function $f:C\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can be uniformly approximated by a function of the form $c_1e^{\langle \lambda_1,x\rangle}+\dots+c_re^{\langle \lambda_r,x\rangle}$. We may conclude that $\int f(x)d\mu(x)=0$ for each continuous function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. But by the Riesz representation theorem, can conclude that $\mu=0$.
What about unbounded measures?
Christian Remling observed that if $\mu$ is compactly supported, then we can analytically continue $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)$ to obtain the Fourier transform, and from the Fourier transform, we can conclude that $\mu$ is determined from $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)$. Let me outline how this is also the case under the minimal assumption that $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)$ is defined on some open set.
We can actually assume that $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)$ is defined on some open neighborhood of $0$ and then perform a translation to obtain the more general result for when $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)$ is just defined on some open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose therefore that $\delta>0$ is a real number so that $\int|e^{\delta\|x\|}|d\mu(x)<\infty$.
Assume that $\Gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$ is a closed loop where $\|\text{Re}(\Gamma(t))\|<\delta$ for all $t$ which is constant in all but one variables so that $\Gamma(t)=(c_1,\dots,c_{r-1},g(t),c_{r+1},\dots,c_n)$ for some loop $g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. Then
$$\int_{\Gamma}\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)d\Gamma(\lambda)=\int_\Gamma\int e^{\langle \lambda,x\rangle}d\mu(x)d\Gamma(\lambda)=\int\int_\Gamma e^{\langle \lambda,x\rangle}d\Gamma(\lambda)d\mu(x)=\int 0d\mu(x)=0$$
by Fubini's theorem. Therefore, by Morera's theorem, the function $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)$ is holomorphic in each variable separately, so $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)$ is homomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^n$ by Hartog's theorem. In particular, we obtain the Fourier transform of $\mu$ from $\mathcal{L}_\mu$.
If $\mathcal{L}_\mu(\lambda)=0$, then the Fourier transform of $\mu$ is zero, so since a measure is determined by its Fourier transform, we can conclude that $\mu=0$ as well.

If $\mu$ is compactly supported, we also have its Fourier transform by holomorphic continuation.

The approach is similar to the one of Joseph van Name, it is a standard type proof:
Let $\mu$ be a finite signed measure on $\mathbb R$ with the property that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} e^{\lambda t} d \mu(t) =0
$$
for all $\lambda <0$, which is a weaker assumption than you require.
Then,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f(t) d \mu(t) =0
$$
for all
$$
f \in A := \{ \sum_{j=0}^n c_j e^{\lambda_i t}: c_1, \ldots, c_n \in \mathbb R, \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n <0 \}
$$
Now, $A$ is a subalgebra of $C_0(\mathbb  R)$ (functions vanishing at infinity) which is separating the points of $\mathbb R$ and hence, $A$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb R)$.
Since, by Riesz Representation Theorem, the space of finite measures is the dual of $C_0(\mathbb  R)$, we get $\mu=0$.
